# render a twig template on condition

Tags: php, symfony, twig, rendering

In my page show.html.twig i have this block

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9  user-wrapper">
<div class="description">                     
{{ render(controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:new')) }}
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a render that render the page new.html.twig, i want to render the page product << `{{ render(controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:product')) }}` >> in the div description only if the user click on the link My Product List .  how do i do that with twig ?

Comment: @Isky this is the link : `<div class="profile-usermenu">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li>
                                    <a  href="{{ path('post') }}">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i>
                                        product </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>`

Comment: One approach is to use the route at `path('post')` to provide an Ajax response to `<div class="description">...</div>.

Comment: @geoB how can i do that, do you have an example ?

Comment: I do, but I can't get to it for several hours.  It someone else does not post an example I'll put mine up.  Hope you can hold out ;).

Comment: @geoB i will make some research on google, if i don't find anything i will lets you know. thx

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I used to "pop-up" a form for sending an e-mail to an entity based on a button appearing with that entity.

You will need to install jquery if not already installed. There are many possible ways to do this. Use your pal Google & "symfony install jquery" to find one. You may also want to find a good javascript debugger for your browser. I use the Firebug add-on in Firefox.

Template with link (edited for brevity). The returned e-mail form appears in `<div id="dialog"></div>`:

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
{% for opp in opportunities %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                ...
                <li><a href="#" value="{{ opp.id }}" id="emailOrganization" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" >E-mail {{ opp.orgName }}</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#emailOrganization", function () {
    var where = $(location).attr('pathname');
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    //replaces URI ending in 'search' with 'oppForm/' + id (of organization)
    var url = where.replace('search', 'oppForm/' + id);
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        //creates dialog box containing e-mail form
        $('#dialog').dialog();
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Send",
                    id: "send",
                    class: "btn-xs btn-primary",
                    click: function () {
                        var formData = $("form").serialize();
                        $.post(url, formData, function (response) {
                            if (response.indexOf("Email sent") >= 0) {
                                $("#send").hide();
                            }
                            $('#dialog').html(response);
                        })
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Close',
                    id: "close",
                    class: "btn-xs btn-primary",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ],
            resizable: true,
        });
        $('#dialog').dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
        $('#dialog').html(data);
    });
});
```

Controller (edited for brevity)

```
/**
 * @Route("/oppForm/{id}", name="opp_form")
 * @Template("default/oppEmail.html.twig")
 */
public function oppFormAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    ...
    $form = $this->createForm(new OpportunityEmailType($oppName, $orgName, $email, $id));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            ...
            }
            $response = new Response("Email sent: " . count($to));

            return $response;
        }
    }

    return [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'id' => $id,
    ];
}
```

Template:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ path('opp_form', {'id': id}) }}" method="post" name="opp_email">
    {# hidden submit button allows functional test; also tested with codeception #}
    <div style="visibility: hidden;"><input type="submit" value="Mail"></div>
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
{{ form_row(form.id) }}
{{ form_row(form.to) }}
{{ form_row(form.from) }}
{{ form_row(form.subject) }}
{{ form_row(form.message) }}
</form>
```